# Dialog width and height issue

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

i use custom dialog but in mobile device and in tab view but design is change when i check on tab

i want same same dialog in all device.

See my below code.

```
private void startDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    int width = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.70);
    int height = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*0.65);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.checkout_alert_dialog);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);


    btn_cancle = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancle);
    btn_cancle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Cancel coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    btn_continue = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
    btn_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, " Ok coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Below is **`Dialog.xml`**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_pointBox"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_chekout_popup"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size"
                android:text="You've chosen to redeem 865 Points and pay 44.44 AED. The Payment process might take Some times, please do not hit the back button or close the app. Would you like to continue. "
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_pointBox"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                />
         <View
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
             android:background="@color/view_color"
             android:layout_above="@+id/linerbutton"
             />
         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/linerbutton"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/lable_cancel"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

             <View
                 android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                 android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
                 android:background="@color/view_color"
                 />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/lable_continue"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
         </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I mention 2 screenshot of my device :

Mobile Device Screen shot:

[image]

Tab Screenshot :

[image]

See in screenshot dialog was change. **So how to i fix it**

Thanks in Advance :

Comment: In your code, you set the size before calling `show()`, have you tried to do it after calling `show()`?

Comment: yes i tried also but didn't work @jhamon

Comment: use dialog instead of AlertDialog.

Comment: This is the normal behavior. If you want the same appearance you must create different layouts under layout folder for different resolutions and orientations.

Comment: how it do that ? @mTak

Comment: See this link(https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

Comment: May be tablet has low resolution screen, check with higher resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at your `layout.xml` Your layout `height` and `width` is `match_parent` then it's create a spaces.

Just replace your `xml` with my `xml`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_250sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_pointBox"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_chekout_popup"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size"
                android:text="You've chosen to redeem 865 Points and pay 44.44 AED. The Payment process might take Some times, please do not hit the back button or close the app. Would you like to continue. "
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_pointBox"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                />
         <View
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
             android:background="@color/view_color"
             android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
             />
         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/linerbutton"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/lable_cancel"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

             <View
                 android:layout_width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                 android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
                 android:background="@color/view_color"
                 />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/lable_continue"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_input_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
         </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And remove below three lines in `java` file **No need to change `height` and `width` at run time**:

```
int width = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.70);
 int height = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*0.65);
 dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

Comment: great this is same what i need. But why remove this 3 lines ??

Comment: beoz this is change your dialog size at run time.

Answer (score 0):

try custom layout

custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageDialog"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textDialog"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#FFF"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDialog"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/declineButton"
android:layout_width="100px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=" Submit "
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/textDialog"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDialog"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

in java file

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
dialog.setTitle("Title");
```

to open dialog use

```
dialog.show();
```

to dismiss dialog use

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: what is a `(R.layout.custom);`

Comment: its a custom dialog xml file now i update my code please check

Answer (score 0):

Replace the

```
myAlertDialog.show();
```

by

```
alertDialog.show();
```

and then

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(width,height);
```

it will work perfectly

complete code:

```
  private void startDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myAlertDialog.setTitle("title");
    myAlertDialog.setMessage("use this");
    AlertDialog alertDialog = myAlertDialog.create();

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int width = (int) ((int)displaymetrics.widthPixels * 0.9);
    int height = (int) ((int)displaymetrics.heightPixels * 0.7);


    myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Intent pictureActionIntent = null;

            pictureActionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, GALLERY_PICTURE);

        }
    });

    myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 15);

        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(width,height);

}
```

if still not working then you can use like this:

```
class DialogView extends DialogFragment {
    Context context;

    public static DialogView newInstance() {
        DialogView f = new DialogView();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme);
        context = this.getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new Dialog(getActivity(), getTheme()) {
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                //do your stuff

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_layout_view, container, false);
        setCancelable(false);
             //  RelativeLayout closeBtn = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_separator);  get button ids like this- gallery camera etc and you can use click listener on that

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * 0.90);
        int height = (int) (metrics.heightPixels * 0.95);
        this.getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        return view;
    }

    public static DisplayMetrics getDeviceMetrics(Context context) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        display.getMetrics(metrics);
        return metrics;
    }

}
```

create xml for that with two button and title

```
button_layout_view
```

then call like this :

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        DialogFragment newFragment = DialogView.newInstance();
       newFragment.show(ft, "");
```

Comment: i tried also this think.  if you see my code perfectly. i add this line in comment `alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(800, 800);`

Comment: sry didn't work brother, i'll try most of examples but  don't know why not change the height and width

Comment: ok brother @MohammadAli i have change in my answer. please check. you can also create dialog like this.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to create DialogFragment and set width and height like that:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    int width = getArguments().getInt(BUNDLE_KEY_WIDTH);
    int height = getArguments().getInt(BUNDLE_KEY_HEIGHT);
    window.setLayout(width, height);
}
```

Comment: but i used alert dialog

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog's width and height is fine in both devices (you are setting them in your `startDialog()` method).
If you want the ImageView to be smaller in tablet devices, so the proportions are the same in both mobile and tablets, you should use a different `dimens` file for them:

First, define a dimen for your image:

*Inside dimens.xml*

```
<dimen name="dialog_image_size">XXXdp</dimen>
```

Then, define the same dimen inside */res/values-sw720dp/dimens.xml* for 10'' tablets and inside */res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml* for 7'' tablets, and set a smaller dp for them.

Now, when you are on a tablet, a different size will be loaded, so you can use a smaller one to keep the same proportions than in mobile.

Comment: i try this but same out it's show me or 1 one more think i'll use `sdp` library for the `height` and `width` size on `xml`

Comment: If you set a smaller dp (for example, 80dp in mobiles, 50dp in 7'' tablets and 35dp in 10'' tablets), it shouldn't be the same at all. Then you can try-error until the proportions are similar for any device.